# How to combine query which counts the data within the same table?

Tags: postgresql

I have this query

```
select 'firstname' as attr_name, count(id) as count_id, count(id) - count(firstname) as count_missing, count(firstname) as count_total from person
union
select 'lastname' as attr_name, count(id) as count_id, count(id) - count(lastname) as count_missing, count(lastname) as count_total from person
```

let say the first query runs for about 5 seconds and the second query runs for 5 seconds as well,
if I run the whole union query, then it would take around 10 seconds. So it basically run individual query and combine the results.

Is there a way to have the same result but the time it take would be lessen?

Can't think of any possible solution other than this.

Comment: "*if I run the whole union query, then it would take around 10 seconds*" - not necessarily. a) the planner might decide to run them in parallel, since they do not depend on each other b) both use the same buffers which improves caching

Comment: Tried it multiple times but it is always the case. Total time is almost the same as running individual query and adding up the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should make only a single scan across the table:

```
WITH result AS (
  SELECT
    count(id) AS count_id,
    count(firstname) AS count_firstname,
    count(lastname) AS count_lastname
  FROM person
)
SELECT
  'firstname' AS attr_name,
  count_id,
  count_id - count_firstname AS count_missing,
  count_firstname AS count_total
FROM result
UNION ALL
SELECT
  'lastname' AS attr_name,
  count_id,
  count_id - count_lastname AS count_missing,
  count_lastname AS count_total
FROM result
```

Comment: Bro you are a life saver! This would increase the performance of my query a lot. I've been thinking of this solution for weeks now.